# Perform Selector After Delegate Method Get Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableView combined with a fetched Results Controller. I deployed controller will change content method, and set the delegate of the frc to self.

But in a function I want to nil out it's delegate so that the will change content delegate method won't be called, and change delegate to self again after some operations to make sure other methods work right, just like this:

```
-(void)function
{
    self.frc.delegate = nil;
    for (id obj in self.frc.fetchedObjects) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[MultiValue class]]) {
            MultiValue * multiValue = (MultiValue *)obj;
            multiValue.isSelected = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        }
    }
    self.frc.delegate = self;
}
```

The problem is, the delegate method (controllerWillChangeContent) will be called after the function method, so after I set self.frc.delegate to self, the delegate method will still be called.

How to solve this? Many thanks.

Comment: Can you paste your some more code??

Comment: already updated. I change the frc in the for loop, but the delegate method will only be called after the return of the function method. What's more, If I put the for loop in another function and call it here, the delegate method will still be called after the return of this function. So i just want to know how to set the delegate to self but forbid the delegate methods to be called. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

Delegating is a way to customize the behavior of objects. It has similarities with subclassing on a per-instance basis. Would you change the hierarchy of an instance's class while the object is living? (Yes, you would do in some situations – very rarely.)

So the delegate of an object is not a "state" of the object, you should change. It is something like the "kind" of an object. You should recheck your whole approach.

Second of all:

The reason is that all changes are collected and the delegate message is sent afterwards, when you reset the delegate. This behavior is better in most situations. From the docs:

> Rather than responding to changes individually (as illustrated in
>   Typical Use), you could just implement controllerDidChangeContent:
>   (which is sent to the delegate when all pending changes have been
>   processed) to reload the table view.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html

To your Q:

You should recheck, why you do not want to be informed about changes in a specific situation while you want to be informed in other situations. This looks like a structural smell. If you are really in such a situation, you should recheck this again. If you are still in such a situation, you can set a flag inside the delegate that signals to ignore a change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But even if I set a flag to ignore changes, the performance is quite bad ( because I change all objects in the fetched results controller. the performance is quite good if I set the delegate to nil).